# "Network request timeout" issue while using in 3G/2G Connectivity Vuforia Cloud Recognition

Tags: java, android, vuforia

I have been working with **Vuforia Cloud Recognition** for android. I am getting "**The network request has timed out**, please check your internet connection and try again." whenever I use in **3G/2G internet connectivity** but If I use in **Wi-Fi network its working fine**.

Is there any possibilities to change the network request time ? or What is the alternative way to make it work..? Please help us ...

Answer (score 0):

You can set time-out like this :

```
HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 17000); //Waiting time 17 sec(Time in milis)
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, 10000); //10 seconds
```

Comment: In Vuforia Colud Recognition the Image Tracking logic is happening inside the C/C++ code. so i want to know how to set request time on that..